# AngularJS nested pages, all gets rendered

Tags: angularjs

I have a HTML page which contains five child html pages. 
Using angularjs $rootScope.$broadcast and $rootScope.$on I am sending common data back and forth between pages. 
The problem is if get/post method fires by any of pages, it renders all the slibbing pages and thus call every ng-event
written in every html page, thus creates performance issue. How to avoid this rendering for every page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to improve your chances of getting a good answer.  It's best if you include code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify your events by page, model, etc.  eg,

```
    $rootScope.$emit('sampleEvent', {
       page: 'pageA',
       data: 'your data if there is any'
    });

    $rootScope.$on('sampleEvent', function(event, data) {
   if(data.page === 'pageA') {
// do something here
}
});
```

also if you are going to use rootscope, just use emit.  Since it's rootscope it has the same affect as broadcast but it provides much better performance.